# Django unorderable types

Tags: python, django

Using Django I want to check if a date is 30 days in the future, `kwargs['datetime']` is a date given from DRF:

```
 from datetime import date, timedelta
 if kwargs['datetime'] > timedelta(days=30):
    pass
```

I get the error: 
**unorderable types: datetime.datetime() > datetime.timedelta()**

Is a Django timezone not compatible with datatime or I'm I doing something else wrong?

Comment: One is an absolute, the other is a delta. You need to convert the delta into an absolute (by using another absolute to refer it to).

Comment: `timedelta` calculates `datetime` if you add or subtract from some other datetime. I am not sure what are you trying to do here.

Comment: @Spaceships Please check my answer.

Comment: You are trying to say if e.g "5 june 1987" is greater than "one week". It's a different category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `timezone` to get the current date time:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

and, to check if the datetime from DRF is after 30 days in future you could add `timedelta` to `now`

```
# or >= as per your requirement
if kwargs['datetime'] > now + timedelta(days=30):
    pass
```

If timezone support is disabled, you could get the current datetime as follows:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

[More Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)